# How to open a file with a known encoding on both Python2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

When opening a file known to be utf-8 on a script that needs to be Py2 & 3 compatible. Is there a nicer way to do it than this:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    long_description = open('README').read()
else:
    long_description = open('README', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Calling `open('README').read()` on Python3.x causes encoding error for systems that default to `ascii`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `io.open` function, which is the built-in `open()` in Python 3.

```
from io import open
long_description = open('README', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open). It's cross-Python compatible:

```
import codecs
long_description = codecs.open('README', encoding='utf-8').read()
```