# Format strings with fixed width (unicode and utf8)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I need to parse and output some data in table-like format. The input is in unicode encoding. Here is the test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

s1 = u'abcd'
s2 = u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4'

print '1234567890'
print '%5s' % s1
print '%5s' % s2
```

It works as expected in case of the simple call like `test.py`:

```
1234567890
 abcd
 αβγδ
```

But if I try to redirect the output to the file `test.py > a.txt`, I getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in 
    print '%5s' % s2
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I convert strings to UTF-8 encoding, like `s2.encode('utf8')` redirection works fine, but data positions are broken:

```
1234567890
 abcd
αβγδ
```

How to force it to work properly in both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to your output stream encoding. In this particular case, since you're using `print`, the output file used is [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).

#### Interactive mode / `stdout` not redirected

When you run Python in the interactive mode, or when you don't redirect `stdout` to a file, Python uses encoding based on the environment, namely locale environment variables, like `LC_CTYPE`. For example, if you run your program like this:

```
$ LC_CTYPE='en_US' python test.py
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

it will use `ANSI_X3.4-1968` for `sys.stdout` (see `sys.stdout.encoding`) and fail. However, is you use `UTF-8` (as you obviously already do):

```
$ LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8' python test.py
1234567890
 abcd
 αβγδ
```

you'll get the expected output.

#### `stdout` redirected to file

When you redirect `stdout` to a file, Python will not try to detect encoding from your environment locale, but it will check another environment variable, [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) (check the source, [`initstdio()` in `Python/pylifecycle.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ccfdb60af7b2db578c1aceb7742cec0330766667/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1578)). For example, this will work as expected:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python test.py >/tmp/output
```

since Python will use `UTF-8` encoding for `/tmp/output` file.

#### Manual `stdout` encoding override

You can also manually re-open `sys.stdout` with the desired encoding (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4374455/404556) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492483/404556) SO question):

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
```

Now `print` will correctly output `str` and `unicode` objects, since the underlying stream writer will convert them to the `UTF-8` on fly.

#### Manual string encoding before output

Of course, you can also manually encode each `unicode` to `UTF-8` `str` prior to output with:

```
print ('%5s' % s2).encode('utf8')
```

but that's tedious and error-prone.

#### Explicit file open

For completeness: when opening files for writing with a specific encoding (like UTF-8) in Python 2, you should use either [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) or [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) because they allow you to specify the encoding (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45537244/404556)), unlike the built-in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
from codecs import open
myfile = open('filename', encoding='utf-8')
```

or:

```
from io import open
myfile = open('filename', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation why it works in the different ways with and without redirection.

Comment: You're welcome. I wanted to put all approaches in one place, since I could only find them scattered.

Answer (score 2):

You should encode `'%5s' % s2` not `s2`. So the following will have the expected output:

```
print ('%5s' % s2).encode('utf8')
```

Comment: After your answer its become obviously :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`print '%5s' % s1` is correct but `print '%5s' % s2` was incorrect. It must `print ('%5s' % s2).encode('utf8')`

Try this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

s1 = u'abcd'
s2 = u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4'

print '1234567890' 
print '%5s' % s1
print ('%5s' % s2).encode('utf8')
```